# Python/FFMPEG command line issues

Tags: 11.04, python, webcam, alsa, ffmpeg

I have a problem with running an FFMPEG command from within a Python script. When I run the following command from the terminal, I can stream video and audio from my attached webcam (Logitech C310) and output to file "out.avi" without any errors.

```
ffmpeg -f alsa -i default -itsoffset 00:00:00 -f video4linux2 -s 1280x720 -r 25 -i /dev/video0 out.avi
```

When I run the same command in a Python script below,

```
def call_command(command):
    subprocess.Popen(command.split(' '))

call_command("ffmpeg -f alsa -i default -itsoffset 00:00:00 -f video4linux2 -s 1280x720 -r 25 -i /dev/video0 out.avi")
```

it gives me this error:

```
Input #0, alsa, from 'default':
  Duration: N/A, start: 1317762562.695397, bitrate: N/A
  Stream #0.0: Audio: pcm_s16le, 44100 Hz, 1 channels, s16, 705 kb/s
[video4linux2 @ 0x165eb10]Cannot find a proper format for codec_id 0, pix_fmt -1.
/dev/video0: Input/output error
```

Could anyone shed some light on what could be going on here? I've tried using os.system() as well as subprocess.call() and it gives me the same errors. I'm not sure where to start on what could be going wrong here. I tried searching for the "video4linux2 Cannot find a proper format for codec_id 0, pix_fmt -1" error, but couldn't find anything consistent.

Comment: I would place the actual command string in a variable and then print the variable to stdout to ensure that you do not need to escape any special characters. Might give you clue as to what is going on.

Comment: Well, what I've also tried is putting the command in a shell script "test.sh", and giving it executable permissions. I then open terminal, and run "./test.sh", and it works.

When I try calling the shell command "./test.sh" from within my Python script, I'm left with the original error as before.

This is the Python command I tried with the test.sh script:
subprocess.call(["./test.sh"])

Comment: Are you still experiencing this issue?

Comment: No, this was moved to Stack Overflow, where I solved the issue: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7666438/831803

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue has been solved in [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7666438).

To summarize the answer, it was a problem with the asker code, he was displaying the output on the screen at the same time that he was trying to record it and this caused a conflict.

Comment: This answer is trying to close an old dead post. Please accept it if you are the OP or vote it up to close this question. Note that it is a community wiki, no rep gain or loss, everyone can edit.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than splitting your "command" string you can call the [subprocess](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html) module with parameter `shell=True`:

```
subprocess.Popen(command, shell=True)
```

However we can't test here if this resolves your codec issue.

Comment: Nope, this doesn't work. I've already tried. The program exits and ffmpeg spits out it's version number, libraries, and this: 

'Hyper fast Audio and Video encoder
usage: ffmpeg [options] [[infile options] -i infile]... {[outfile options] outfile}...

Use -h to get full help or, even better, run 'man ffmpeg''